# How to average data in files across multiple folders

Tags: r

I have a directory with the folders A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3. Each folder contains files that are named in the same way for each folder, say: x, y, z. And each file has one numeric variable. I’d like to take the average of A1/x, A2/x, A3/x. And then the same for y and z. And then repeat for the B folders. Does anyone have any ideas on how to code this up? I’m working in R for this project but if another language is better suited I’d be open to that.

Comment: This is possible in R. However, while it is understood that coding is challenging if you don't know where to start, SO is not a code writing service. Please review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), particular the part about making a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Otherwise your question is likely to get downvoted and/or closed. Asking a good question reduces the time it takes to answer, and ensures answers completely address your issue. Hope this info is helpful.